# Parsing a Date with Month name to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to parse the following date format to a DateTime object in C#.

```
"19 Aug 2010 17:48:35 GMT+00:00"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_).

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss \\G\\M\\Tzzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As suggested in the comments below, `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is a good thing to be aware of and use if you are doing a desktop application.

Comment: Is there a default or "out of the box provider" that lets it try to parse any date/time format it can reasonably think of? I tried browsing the MSDN docs but left without really understanding.

Comment: @robr, this is probably really too late for you, but I've used `DateTime.Parse` pretty well to that effect - it accepted "March 1", "3\1\2013" and "03\01\2013" without issue.

Comment: Consider using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` because for any none English month **an exception** is thrown. Have a look at this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vndkGd).

Comment: Here is the updated link to the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

Comment: Thanks @g5thomas - I guess MSFT is doing through their every-10-year docs reorganization again!

Answer (score -1):

I know my answer is a bit out of scope, but it might be helpful anyway. My problem was a bit different, I had to extract the highest date of a string, that might be in various formats (1.1.98, 21.01.98, 21.1.1998, 21.01.1998). These are two static methods that can be added to any class:

```
public static DateTime ParseDate(string value)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    if (value.Length <= 7) // 1.1.98, 21.3.98, 1.12.98, 
        DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "d.M.yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
    else if (value.Length == 8 && value[5] == '.') // 21.01.98
        DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
    else if (value.Length <= 9) // 1.1.1998, 21.1.1998, 1.12.1998
        DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "d.M.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
    else if (value.Length == 10) // 21.01.1998
        DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
    return date;
}

public static DateTime? ExtractDate(string text)
{
    DateTime? ret = null;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}");
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        DateTime date = ParseDate(match.Value);
        if (ret == null || ret < date)
            ret = date;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: None of the date formats you've presented come close to what's in the question, which also has time and timezone/offset components, so how does any of this actually answer or apply to the question? If the gist is "Use `TryParseExact()`" then that's already been covered. Further, it's strange that you return the value from the `out` parameter of `TryParseExact()` whether it failed or not without giving any indication to the caller (other than the value being `DateTime.MinValue`) that it failed to parse. Pass `"00.00.0000"` or `"11.22.33.44"` to either method and see if the results make sense.

Comment: Yeah maybe this post would have deserved it's own thread. It's also not supposed to be absolutely failsafe, but rather to give an idea how to cope with heterogenous date formats.