# Convert string to standard c# datetime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have this string 
`01 Nov 2018 10:50` and I want to convert it to Datetime format like this
`2018-11-01 10:50:00.000`

I've tried this

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01 Nov 2018 10:50", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",  null)
```

But I'm getting exception

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

Comment: What do you think that format string (yyyy-MM...) means? Please refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I think there is `.` not `,`

Comment: Yeah. Why do you thik "01 Nov" is parsable with "yyyy-MM", just to start? And where is your hour, minute etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a Date with Month name to C# DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525003/parsing-a-date-with-month-name-to-c-sharp-datetime)

Comment: It looks like you are working with excel which separates the milliseconds with a comma.  Try replacing the comma with a period and then try again.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' @dimitry bychenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the other format:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("01 Nov 2018 10:50", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm")
```

After having `date` object, you can convert to the format you want:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff");
```

Answer (score 3):

`ParseExact` expects a format definition that matches your input as second parameter.

The format definition that matches your input is `"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"`.

Refer to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for valid format definitions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ParseExact` you are supposed to pass the exact format that you want to parse on the second parameter of the method. You are setting an absolutely different format to the `ParseExact` method. Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01 Nov 2018 10:50", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm",  null)
```

You got complete reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2